# Is it true that $p_{n}+p_{n+1}>p_{n+2}$ for all $n\geq 2\ ?$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p_{n}$ denotes the $n$-th prime number. Is it true that $p_{n}+p_{n+1}>p_{n+2}$ for all $n\geq 2\ ?$

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Check $n=2$ and $n=3$ by hand. A [variant of Bertrand's postulate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466844/primes-between-n-and-2n) assures, that there are two primes between $p_n$ and $2p_n$, when $n\geq 4$. Let's call the bigger one $p_k$, then $k\geq n$+2 and 
$$p_n+p_{n+1}\geq 2p_n > p_k \geq p_{n+2}$$

Comment: +1 It is more of a generalization, than a variant. For all $\alpha > 1$, there exists an $n$ such that for $m > n$, there is a prime in the interval $m, \alpha m$. The 'variant' that you are using is $\alpha = \frac{4}{3}$, with $n=12$.

Comment: Thanks, @CalvinLin, I agree with the generalization and $\frac{4}{3}$ of course works, since this yields two primes between $m$ and $\frac{16}{9}m<2m$. But why did you pick precisely $\frac 43$?

Comment: It is one of those well-known facts that are quoted without proof in math competitions.