# Prove that if $ n > 2 $ then between $n$ and $n!$ is at least one prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Prove that if $ n > 2 $ then between $n$ and $n!$ is at least one prime.

Ok I can see that it's obviously true, but what to use to prove it?

Comment: how can it be obviously true if you do not know how to prove it?!

Comment: You could also use [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466844/primes-between-n-and-2n) and note that $2n \leq n!$ for $n > 2$.

Comment: In fact, there is always a prime between $n$ and $2n$, $\forall$ $n \ge 1$. See: Bertrand's Postulate.

Comment: @mapierce271 there is a difference between $n!+1$ and $n!$ Most of the answers use that $+1$, I think (the others rely on Bertrand's postulate, which is sort of absurd as this is a basic exercise...)

Comment: @AhmedHussein, but the proof of that is actually considerably harder —indeed, it is a famous theorem!

Comment: @AhmedHussein yes I've seen this, but this proof's too hard for me.

Comment: Alright. I'll prove this one.

Answer (score 2):

Let $n \in \Bbb N$, such that $n \ge 2$.

We have that any prime $p < n$ is an element of $\{1,2,...,n-1\}$, hence $p|n!$ $(*)$.

Now, we have that $n!$ and $n! -1$ are coprime. If there is no prime divisor $p$ of $n! - 1$, such that $p > n$, then the prime divisors of $n! - 1$ are $<n$, but this means that $n!$ and $n! - 1$ share a common divisor by $(*)$, which is impossible. Hence $n! - 1$ must have a prime divisor $>n$, say $q$. It's clear that $q \le n! - 1 < n!$, but $q > n$. Therefore:

There is a prime number $q$, such that $n < q < n!$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$ be any prime divisor of $n!-1$. Then $p\leq n!-1<n!$. We easily see that $p\nmid n!$, so $p$ doesn't divide any number up to $n$, so we don't have $p\leq n$, so $p>n$.

Thus $n<p<n!$.