# Is there a factorial of the form $p m^2$ greater than 720?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial, square-numbers

The question is motivated [by this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/n-is-never-a-perfect-square-if-n-geq2-is-there-a-proof-of-this-that-doesn)

As $6! = 5\cdot 12^2$, in order to prove that $6!$ is not a square, we need to know that $5$ exists between $3$ and $6$. So Chebyshev's theorem seems necessary here. However, I believe this is the only case (other than 2) where $n! = p m^2$ with $p$ prime; the reason must be also in some result of Chebyshev kind: there are at least two different primes between $n$ and $\frac {n}{2}$ or something similar. But I have no proper proof.

Comment: I believe that *prime number theorem* implies that there cannot be such factorial.

Comment: @barakmanos, I don't believe this. It can only imply that there no *infinitely many* such factorials.

Comment: search for prime gap upper bounds in the form of $\pi(x+x^\theta)-\pi(x)$ with $\theta<1$ (I think some exponent between $0.5$ and $0.6$ is the current best result), and check the small cases by hand.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution :

$$10!=7\times 720^2$$ This is almost surely the largest one.

This PARI/GP program

```
? for(n=0,2000,if(isprime(core(n!),2)==1,print(n)))
2
6
10
?
```

shows that the only solutions upto $n=2000$ are $2,6,10$. To prove the conjecture, it would be enough to show that for every even number $n\ge 2000$,
there are at least two primes $p,q$ with $\frac{n}{2}<p<q<n$.

Comment: Great finding! How could I overlook this? Any ideas of the proof?

Comment: The above statement about primes is a generalization of [Bertrand's postulate.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)  [Ramanujan proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime) that two such primes always exist for $n \geq 11$.  There's also a proof by Erdos that shows that for all $k$, there exists an $n$ such that $k$ primes exist between $n$ and $2n$.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466844/primes-between-n-and-2n seems relevant

Comment: Yes, this actually completes the proof.